# Getting a SyntaxError when using a variable with a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

When the following code in my node.js-application is executed I get an Error saying:

**SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*ha*/: Nothing to repeat at new RegExp () at Object.store.findSimilarSongs**

app.js snippet:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res, next) {

    store.findSimilarSongs(req.query.search, function (err, songs) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500, "An Error occurred");
            next(err);
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });
            res.write(JSON.stringify(songs));
            searchQuery=[];
        }
        res.end();
    });
});
```

the function "findSimilarSongs" in my store.js:

```
findSimilarSongs: function (query, callback) {
        db.music.find({$or:[{'title': new RegExp("*"+query+"*", "i")},{'interpret': new RegExp("*"+query+"*", "i")}]}, callback);
    }
```

I am pretty new to regular expressions especially combined with mongodb/mongoskin.
Until the error occurs, everything works pretty much fine.
The *ha* mentioned in the error-message is exactly what I typed into the searchbar.

Sadly I do not have the option to do this task with any other means, but javascript/jquery, node.js(modules:express, mongoskin) and mongodb.

Comment: A `*` has special meaning in  a regular expression. By having it at the beginning, you've put it in an invalid position. If you wanted to match a literal, `*` character, then you need to escape it with a backslash. And since JS string literals use the back slash as a special character, you need to escape the backslash too. So `"\\*" + query + "\\*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "*nothing to repeat*", as the regex you constructed was `/*hal*/`. That's definitely invalid - you cannot start with the [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). I guess you either wanted a fuzzy match:

```
new RegExp(".*"+query+".*, 'i')
```

or a literal star:

```
new RegExp("\\*"+query+"\\*", 'i')
```

Comment: Tested both of your versions but got the same error:
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*ma*/: Nothing to repeat at new RegExp (<anonymous>)